# Push notification for Android app with Sharepoint 2013

Tags: android, sharepoint, push-notification, sharepoint-2013

I need to write an Android 6+ App with push notification about activities/resources updated in Sharepoint 2013. Polling is not a viable option...
I would like to know if there is some kind of Sharepoint's service the handle push notification and the way to connect it to android apps or otherwise the best way to achieve this (Sharepoint that connect to CloudFire maybe?)... My app should be native.

Thank you very much indeed...